# Why does my ProgressBar update late when using background worker?

Tags: vb.net

What am I doing wrong? Please help. My progress bar is updating only after ShowData() event is finished. I want it to update during the ShowData() event.

This is my click event, where ShowData() is in the module and is work being done.

```
Private Sub ListView1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ListView1.SelectedIndexChanged
    Application.EnableVisualStyles()
    frmProgress.Show()
    showData()
    AddToDatabaseToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = False
    frmProgress.Close()
End Sub
```

This is Progress bar form load and background worker code.

```
 Private Sub frmProgress_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Application.EnableVisualStyles()
    With ProgressBar1
        .Style = ProgressBarStyle.Blocks
        .Visible = True
    End With
    Me.Text = "IDB"
    Label1.Text = "Loading... Please wait"
    Me.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor
    If Not BackgroundWorker1.IsBusy = True Then
        BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
    For i = 0 To 100
        If BackgroundWorker1.CancellationPending = True Then
            e.Cancel = True
            Exit For
        Else
            DoHeavyWork()
            BackgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(i)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged
    ProgressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage
    Label2.Text = e.ProgressPercentage.ToString() + " %"
End Sub
Private Sub DoHeavyWork()
    Thread.Sleep(100)
End Sub
Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted
    If e.Cancelled = True Then
        MessageBox.Show("Cancelled")
        ProgressBar1.Value = 0
        Label1.Text = ""
    ElseIf e.Error IsNot Nothing Then
        MessageBox.Show(e.Error.Message)
    Else
        Label1.Text = "Loading... Done"
        BackgroundWorker1.CancelAsync()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What Actually is the ShowData Method?  Is that blocking the UI thread?

Comment: And wouldn't it make more sense to close your progress form in the run worker complete event rather than on the Main form?

Comment: Yes ShowData is blocking the UI thread i believe, that is why I have background worker. I will try with closing the form from run worker, but I thisnk UI thread is the issue. If you could give me an example how to use BGW correctly, from there I think I can work it out. I have the message box pop up when show data is finished, then after that progress bar works perfectly.

Comment: What ever you're doing in showData() should be done within the background worker, perhaps where you currently have DoHeavyWork.  Maybe look at moving the background worker to your main form rather than in the progress form

Comment: I have a feeling that I may have recommended this to you previously but I may be thinking of someone else. I strongly recommend that you make use of my tried and tested progress dialogue [here](https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?869567). It is objectively better than what you are doing there.

Comment: This is where I am confused. Which form does what? I will try your suggestion Hursey, swapping forms, and see how that goes. I did try putting the ShowData into BGW, and was coming up with STA error. Thank you for your answers much appreciated.

Comment: Yes jmcilhinney, I thought that I can use a stopwatch to achieve my task, but seems a inefficient way of doing things. I did have a look at your example and am trying to adjust to my situation, but am confused with what goes where. Hopefully one of these suggestions will work out in the end. Thank you for your help so far.

Comment: What's to be confused about? The `BackgroundWorkerForm` has `DoWork`, `ProgressChanged` and `RunWorkerCompleted` events and you handle them in your own form just as you would for a `BackgroundWorker`. You're trying to make it harder than it is. It's difficult to provide an answer based on that demo, because it's difficult to provide all the required code and instructions for that demo here. I am about to update that original thread though, because I have created a C# version too, so I'll provide a simpler set of instructions and let you know when it's done.

Comment: Thank you my friend, looking forward to it. Just to clarify, this is the first time I am attempting this code, so there is confusion. Just trying to understand it in my own head. I think you are right I am trying too much and making it too complicated. :)

Comment: Follow the link again. I have provided an updated attachment and also a new post that provides some simple instructions.

Comment: You are the man jmcilhinney. Thank you greatly. this is exactly what I needed , a good teacher. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question was answered in the comments, using code written by jmcilhinney and replicated here for standard "SO answers linking to offsite resources should include salient points of the resource to guard against link rot"

BackgroundWorkerForm.vb

```
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class BackgroundWorkerForm

#Region "Fields"

    Private ReadOnly onDoWork As DoWorkEventHandler
    Private ReadOnly onProgressChanged As ProgressChangedEventHandler
    Private ReadOnly onRunWorkerCompleted As RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler

#End Region 'Fields

#Region "Constructors"

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Creates a new instance of the <see cref="BackgroundWorkerForm"/> class.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <remarks>
    ''' Parameterless constructor is private to ensure handlers are provided for <see cref="BackgroundWorker"/>.
    ''' </remarks>
    Private Sub New()
        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()
    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Creates a new instance of the <see cref="BackgroundWorkerForm" /> class.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="onDoWork">
    ''' Handler for the <see cref="BackgroundWorker.DoWork">RunWorkerCompleted</see> event of a <see cref="BackgroundWorker"/>.
    ''' </param>
    Public Sub New(onDoWork As DoWorkEventHandler)
        Me.New()

        Me.onDoWork = onDoWork

        'AddHandler is used for local event handlers so that remote event handlers can be registered first and thus executed first.

        'Remote event handlers
        AddHandler BackgroundWorker1.DoWork, onDoWork

        'Local event handlers
        AddHandler BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted, AddressOf BackgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted
    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Creates a new instance of the <see cref="BackgroundWorkerForm" /> class.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="onDoWork">
    ''' Handler for the <see cref="BackgroundWorker.DoWork">RunWorkerCompleted</see> event of a <see cref="BackgroundWorker"/>.
    ''' </param>
    ''' <param name="onProgressChanged">
    ''' Handler for the <see cref="BackgroundWorker.ProgressChanged">RunWorkerCompleted</see> event of a <see cref="BackgroundWorker"/>.
    ''' </param>
    Public Sub New(onDoWork As DoWorkEventHandler,
                   onProgressChanged As ProgressChangedEventHandler)
        Me.New()

        Me.onDoWork = onDoWork
        Me.onProgressChanged = onProgressChanged

        'AddHandler is used for local event handlers so that remote event handlers can be registered first and thus executed first.

        'Remote event handlers
        AddHandler BackgroundWorker1.DoWork, onDoWork
        AddHandler BackgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged, onProgressChanged

        'Local event handlers
        AddHandler BackgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged, AddressOf BackgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged
        AddHandler BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted, AddressOf BackgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted

        'A ProgressChanged handler has been provided so the ProgressBar will be updated explicitly based on the BackgroundWorker.
        BackgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = True
        ProgressBar1.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Continuous
    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Creates a new instance of the <see cref="BackgroundWorkerForm" /> class.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="onDoWork">
    ''' Handler for the <see cref="BackgroundWorker.DoWork">RunWorkerCompleted</see> event of a <see cref="BackgroundWorker"/>.
    ''' </param>
    ''' <param name="onRunWorkerCompleted">
    ''' Handler for the <see cref="BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted">RunWorkerCompleted</see> event of a <see cref="BackgroundWorker"/>.
    ''' </param>
    Public Sub New(onDoWork As DoWorkEventHandler,
                   onRunWorkerCompleted As RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler)
        Me.New()

        Me.onDoWork = onDoWork
        Me.onRunWorkerCompleted = onRunWorkerCompleted

        'AddHandler is used for local event handlers so that remote event handlers can be registered first and thus executed first.

        'Remote event handlers
        AddHandler BackgroundWorker1.DoWork, onDoWork
        AddHandler BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted, onRunWorkerCompleted

        'Local event handlers
        AddHandler BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted, AddressOf BackgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted
    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Creates a new instance of the <see cref="BackgroundWorkerForm" /> class.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="onDoWork">
    ''' Handler for the <see cref="BackgroundWorker.DoWork">RunWorkerCompleted</see> event of a <see cref="BackgroundWorker"/>.
    ''' </param>
    ''' <param name="onProgressChanged">
    ''' Handler for the <see cref="BackgroundWorker.ProgressChanged">RunWorkerCompleted</see> event of a <see cref="BackgroundWorker"/>.
    ''' </param>
    ''' <param name="onRunWorkerCompleted">
    ''' Handler for the <see cref="BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted">RunWorkerCompleted</see> event of a <see cref="BackgroundWorker"/>.
    ''' </param>
    Public Sub New(onDoWork As DoWorkEventHandler,
                   onProgressChanged As ProgressChangedEventHandler,
                   onRunWorkerCompleted As RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler)
        Me.New()

        Me.onDoWork = onDoWork
        Me.onProgressChanged = onProgressChanged
        Me.onRunWorkerCompleted = onRunWorkerCompleted

        'AddHandler is used for local event handlers so that remote event handlers can be registered first and thus executed first.

        'Remote event handlers
        AddHandler BackgroundWorker1.DoWork, onDoWork
        AddHandler BackgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged, onProgressChanged
        AddHandler BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted, onRunWorkerCompleted

        'Local event handlers
        AddHandler BackgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged, AddressOf BackgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged
        AddHandler BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted, AddressOf BackgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted

        'A ProgressChanged handler has been provided so the ProgressBar will be updated explicitly based on the BackgroundWorker.
        BackgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = True
        ProgressBar1.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Continuous
    End Sub

#End Region 'Constructors

#Region "Properties"

    Public WriteOnly Property SupportsCancellation As Boolean
        Set
            BackgroundWorker1.WorkerSupportsCancellation = value

            'If the worker can be cancelled, show the Cancel button and make the form big enough to see it.
            cancelWorkButton.Visible = Value
            ClientSize = New Size(284,
                                  If(Value, 76, 47))
        End Set
    End Property

#End Region 'Properties

#Region "Methods"

    Private Sub BackgroundWorkerForm_Shown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Shown
        'Start the background work when the form is displayed.
        BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()
    End Sub

    Private Sub cancelWorkButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cancelWorkButton.Click
        'Disable the button to prevent another click.
        cancelWorkButton.Enabled = False

        'Cancel the background work.
        BackgroundWorker1.CancelAsync()
    End Sub

    Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(sender As Object, e As ProgressChangedEventArgs)
        'Update the ProgressBar.
        ProgressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage
    End Sub

    Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(sender As Object, e As RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs)
        'Close the form when the work is done.
        Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub BackgroundWorkerForm_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
        'Remote event handlers.

        If onDoWork IsNot Nothing Then
            RemoveHandler BackgroundWorker1.DoWork, onDoWork
        End If

        If onProgressChanged IsNot Nothing Then
            RemoveHandler BackgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged, onProgressChanged
        End If

        If onRunWorkerCompleted IsNot Nothing Then
            RemoveHandler BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted, onRunWorkerCompleted
        End If

        'Local event handlers
        RemoveHandler BackgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged, AddressOf BackgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged
        RemoveHandler BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted, AddressOf BackgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted
    End Sub

#End Region 'Methods

End Class
```

Form1.vb

```
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Threading

Public Class Form1

    'This method will be executed by the BackgroundWorker in the dialogue.
    Private Sub BackgroundWorkerForm_DoWork(sender As Object, e As DoWorkEventArgs)
        Dim worker = DirectCast(sender, BackgroundWorker)

        'Simulate some time-consuming work.
        For i = 0 To 100
            If worker.CancellationPending Then
                e.Cancel = True

                Exit For
            End If

            If reportProgressCheckBox.Checked Then
                worker.ReportProgress(i)
            End If

            Thread.Sleep(100)
        Next
    End Sub

    'This method will be executed by the BackgroundWorker in the dialogue.
    Private Sub BackgroundWorkerForm_ProgressChanged(sender As Object, e As ProgressChangedEventArgs)
        statusLabel.Text = (e.ProgressPercentage / 100).ToString("p0")
    End Sub

    'This method will be executed by the BackgroundWorker in the dialogue.
    Private Sub BackgroundWorkerForm_RunWorkerCompleted(sender As Object, e As RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs)
        statusLabel.Text = If(e.Cancelled, "Operation cancelled", "Operation complete")
    End Sub

    Private Sub runButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles runButton.Click
        'Display the dialogue to initiate the background work.
        Using waitDialogue = GetWaitDialogue()
            waitDialogue.ShowDialog()
        End Using
    End Sub

    Private Function GetWaitDialogue() As BackgroundWorkerForm
        Dim dialogue As BackgroundWorkerForm

        'Only provide a ProgressChanged handler if the corresponding CheckBox is checked.
        If reportProgressCheckBox.Checked Then
            dialogue = New BackgroundWorkerForm(AddressOf BackgroundWorkerForm_DoWork,
                                                AddressOf BackgroundWorkerForm_ProgressChanged,
                                                AddressOf BackgroundWorkerForm_RunWorkerCompleted)
        Else
            dialogue = New BackgroundWorkerForm(AddressOf BackgroundWorkerForm_DoWork,
                                                AddressOf BackgroundWorkerForm_RunWorkerCompleted)
        End If

        'Only display a Cancel button if the corresponding CheckBox is checked.
        dialogue.SupportsCancellation = allowCancellationCheckBox.Checked

        Return dialogue
    End Function

End Class
```